# Search element using div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to search elementid based on div class as my element id in html page keep on changing based on different navigation, but my div class seems to be same everytime.
 I want to access the elementid and then i need to change the style.overflow ='visible' .
Also even my elementid are getting changed it has same postfix pattern, is there a way to search for the elementid using pattern in jquery ?

Please help as I'm new to javascript as well as jquery.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, then to select an element by class you can use a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
var elems = $(".someClass");
```

To select elements whose `id` starts with a certain value you can use a "[attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector:

```
var elems = $("[id^='something']");
```

There are numerous other [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you can use. The best place to look is always the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: you should make OP aware that $('.someClass') is not very efficient as it requires iteration over all DOM elements.  If possible you should try to be more specific with selectors for efficiency such as $('div.someClass')

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you check-out the jQuery selectors list: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

It will help you better understand how to harness the power of jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/ has a complete list of jQuery functions, I remember it blew me away the number of things you can do so easily when I started learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an element by class:

```
$(".class-name");
```

or by id:

```
$("#elementId");
```

Keep in mind that the return value is a jQuery object (array) so you'll need to use an indexer to get the element:

```
var element = $(".class-name")[0];
var elementId = element.id;
```

Here's a great place to start:

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery